# F# return type coercion

Tags: f#, types, coercion, type-systems

In F# I have a function that returns System.Linq.Expression instances:

```
and System.Object with
  member this.ToExpression() = 
    match this with
    | :? System.Int32 -> Expression.Constant(this) :> Expression
    | :? System.Boolean -> Expression.Constant(this) :> Expression
    | :? Tml.Runtime.Seq as s -> s.ToExpression()
    | _ -> failwith "bad expression"
```

If I omit the type coercions on the return values F# will infer the return type of the function to ConstantExpression. My first thought was to explicitly mark the return type as being : #Expression, but that didn't work. Is there a more elegant way of doing this that doesn't involve manually casting return types to the most generic type?

Thanks.

Edit: Thanks to all of you for the answers. I'll go with the explicit return type + upcast scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a couple ways you might prefer:

```
open System.Linq.Expressions 

type System.Object with
    member this.ToExpression() : Expression =  // explicit
        match this with 
        | :? System.Int32 -> upcast Expression.Constant(this) // upcast
        | :? System.Boolean -> Expression.Constant(this) :> _ // _
        | _ -> failwith "bad expression"
```

By explicitly stating the return type on the `member` declaration, you can then infer it in the body, e.g. via `_` as a "please infer this type for me" or by using the `upcast` operator which will infer the type to up-cast to from the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any significantly more elegant way of writing this, unfrotunately.

The compiler requires that all branches of the `match` expression will have the same return type and it doesn't implicitly insert any coercions. You can use the `upcast` keyword to insert a coercion without specifying the target type - in this case, the compiler will use other information (such as type annotations) to determine the type and you won't have to repeat the type:

```
and System.Object with 
  member this.ToExpression() : Expression =  
    match this with 
    | :? System.Int32 -> upcast Expression.Constant(this) 
    | :? System.Boolean -> upcast Expression.Constant(this)
    | :? Tml.Runtime.Seq as s -> upcast s.ToExpression() 
    | _ -> failwith "bad expression"
```

I added type annotation and `upcast` to each of the expression and type annotation, so the F# compiler infers that the `upcast` needs to coerce the result to `Expression`. The only place where the compiler inserts implicit coercions is when calling a function, so you could also write the following (but I'm not sure if it's any better):

```
// Thanks to implicit coercions, we don't even need #type
let expr (a:Expression) = a

// and then for example:
| :? System.Int32 -> Expression.Constant(this) |> expr
```

For some reason, `upcast` is a keyword, so you cannot use it with pipelining, so definining a function like this may have some benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking this is not removing the coersion but in my opinion it's a bit better on the eye (and will save you a little bit of typing too :) )

```
open System.Linq.Expressions

let Constant obj = Expression.Constant(obj) :> Expression

type System.Object with
    member this.ToExpression()
        match this with 
        | :? System.Int32 -> Constant(this)
        | :? System.Boolean -> Constant(this)
        | _ -> failwith "bad expression"
```

since the type of Constant is a'->Expression it will work in both cases. The down side is of cause that you will have to define a function for each of the Expression factory methods you are going to use.